# With JS how can I get the value of the div's flex-direction property?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

In trying to solve this using Windows Chrome 59 I used devtools to inspect the  properties.

```
let el = document.getElementById("divId");
```

Then by inspecting the value of el, I see that the object structure shows:

```
>style:CSSStyleDeclaration
```

Then clicking the pointer to expand style I see that its object structure shows a property for flexDirection: "" (empty). I know that my css has set the flex-direction to column:

```
flex-direction: column;
```

Is it not possible to retrieve this value as set by my program? I need to see this change from flex-direction: row to switch my js code's resizing logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it using [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). `getComputedStyle` returns a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object, and you can the value of the desired property by using `getPropertyValue()` method, or by accessing the property directly.

```js
const el = document.getElementById("divId");

const style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

console.log(style.getPropertyValue('flex-direction')); // using the method

console.log(style.flexDirection); // accessing the property
```

```css
#divId {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="divId"></div>
```

Comment: Yes! That's perfect. Thank you for the very quick Answer.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using `window` object?